# Gnome change virtual desktops by moving mouse to edge of the screen

Tags: mouse, gnome, virtual-desktop

I remember with older window managers you could switch virtual desktops by moving the mouse to the edge of the screen and your virtual desktop would change.

So if you have two virtual desktops left and right, if you move the mouse to an edge your virtual desktop would switch to that one.

Is this feature in gnome or do you need to use keyboard shortcuts and the virtual desktop widget in the panel.

Answer (score 2):

The Compiz window manager supports this through its "Viewport Switcher" plugin, if I remember correctly. (Get `compizconfig-settings-manager` aka `ccsm`.)

If you're using plain Metacity, it does not have such a feature.