# Gnome change virtual desktops by moving mouse to edge of the screen - Delay

Tags: gnome, switch, compiz, virtual-desktop, delay

In [Gnome change virtual desktops by moving mouse to edge of the screen](https://superuser.com/questions/93482/gnome-change-virtual-desktops-by-moving-mouse-to-edge-of-the-screen) is described how to switch virtual desktops by mouse. Is it posible to define delay after which vdestop is switched? Respectively is it posibble to define vdesktops are not swithing instantly.